# throw non-exception objects

Tags: c++, exception

`C++` allows `throw`ing any kind of objects. From `exception`s to `string` and even `int`.
But I've never seen any real world application of `throw`ing anything other than `exception`s.

My question is, what is the application for `throw`ing non-`exception` objects?

Comment: For example, your application may already have some error-description mechanism and you cannot inherit it from exception.

Comment: Practically speaking, there is (virtually) no application for throwing anything other than an `exception`.

Comment: @AlexTelishev Then it might be the better idea to encapsulate _'some error-description mechanism'_ within exceptions derived from `std::exception`, rather than catching enum error-codes or alike directly IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a viewpoint of practicality, there is almost<sup>1</sup> no application for throwing `string`s, `int`s, or anything else that isn't derived from `std::exception`.

This isn't because there's no indication for doing so, but because there are contra-indications that suggest why you shouldn't.

There are two main reasons why you wouldn't want to throw anything that's not derived from `std::exception`:

1. **Exception safety.** If you throw, for example, a `std::string` and the construction or copy of that `string` raises another exception, `terminate` will be called and your process will cease to exist.  You'll never get a chance to `catch` that `std::string`.
2. **Usability.**  Throwing derivitaves of `std::exception` makes it possible to `catch (const std::exception&)` in a generic fashion.  If you throw something else, you will need a `catch` for that case.

A good discussion of exceptions can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html).

---

**<sup>1</sup> Almost no application [...]:**  There are exclusions to every rule, but even in acknowledging this, I have never seen a *legitimate* exclusion to throwing a derivitave of `std::exception`.

Comment: Having rules to write a safe object in regards to have it throw-able do not means you cannot write one. In the video games industry, it is likely the use of std::string is forbidden, and std::logic_exception for example depends on it… so exception header will be forbidden too

Comment: I don't think something like `throw std::string("oops")` could actually result in `terminate`.  If the constructor throws, the throw-expression never gets evaluated so there is no second throw, just like `throw f(std::string("oops"))` would not call `f`.

Comment: @aschepler:  It will at least result in the wrong exception being thrown.

Comment: @galop1n:  I didn't say you *couldn't.*  I said you usually shouldn't.

Comment: _Almost no application_ how about emulating hard exception (with ie. int), that is supposed to bypass all catch clauses and end in main()?

Comment: @marcin_j:  That might be an exception, no pun.  Pretty rare, though.

Comment: Everyone keeps touting 2nd point as a good thing, yet provides no real examples where it's an actual use instead of abuse. Exceptions are exceptional errors that happen very rarely but probably can still be handled in some way and probably should be, why would you want to catch a generic std::exception and then ignore it what can you even do with an exception that you know nothing of? Not catching an exception provides a literally better error message, printing even the actual concrete type of exception that was not caught, and lets you see that there's something actually wrong with your code.

Answer (score 5):

More of a hack rather than a language feature, you could throw an object and then catch it to force a function to "return" something different than its normal return type.

```
int aFunc()
{
    throw foo(); // if you catch that foo, you 've imitated returning foo
    return 0; // ok just an int
}
```

This would ofcourse be a terrible design choice and a violation of type safety offered by C++ but say you have a function heavily used in a huge code base and you want to try some change (which involves altering the return type) then that would be dirty way of trying something out before  actually implementing the change (and grep the whole code base to do changes)

EDIT:

You should read the post more carefully. I 've said "a terrible design choice" and "a violation of type safety offered by C++" and "before  actually implementing the change". If that is not enough of a warning I don't think those comments or downvotes would be.

On the other hand try altering the return type of a function used 666 times in a code base of 6e06 lines to find out that it's not what you want after you've uploaded it on your version control system and broke the compile multiple times for developers working on other plattforms than you.

If there was a shortcut wouldn't you want to know about it? Wouldn't you use it until implementing the change and actually posting it to your code base?

Even if the answer to those questions is "NO" I thought this post was about exploring possibilities, and just mentioning one is not per se 'evil'. I personally heard this one from a Bjarne's talk http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style who afterwards said the same things about not using such things.

Comment: _'if you catch that foo, you 've imitated returning foo'_ **Do not** misuse exceptions this way!

Comment: -1. Very bad advice. Exceptions are for exceptional situations not general flow control.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Actually the advice is very good.  He clearly states that this should should NOT be done.  Why downvote someone pointing out a technically possible use and clearly stating that it is a bad idea? At least it gives the poster a chance to recognize the abuse if he comes across it in the wild.

I've actually seen production code that used this kind of hack.  See http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004 for a more complete example.

Comment: @marack You're right, I missed that part of his post.

Answer (score 1):

You throw whatever you wants, it will always be an exception as you throw it. The standard library use classes inherited from std::exception and this is a design choice.

If you feel like throwing an enumeration is enough for needs, as an example, why enforce you to throw an object…

Comment: So `throw 1;` will work with `catch(std::exception)`? Cause that's what "You throw whatever you wants, it will always be an exception as you throw it." implies.

Comment: the object you throw is an exception, it does not means that the type is std::exception. You have to catch the correct type documented by the API call you are using.

Comment: The implication here is that there is no reason to not `throw` just whatever you want.  That implication I disagree with.  There is almost never a good reason to throw anything *other* than something derived from `std::exception`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore there's more to life than writing web servers over and over. Could you genuinely tell me what are you doing that you end up using a catchall net instead of reading documentation and handling each exception individually, like you should be? Consider `std::vector::at`, don't tell me you would prefer to catch `std::exception` over `std::out_of_range`, and given that you know no type of exception, you can't even be sure what exactly triggered that exception... The attribute of being derived from `std::exception` in my eyes is completely worthless and I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: @Sahsahae while I don't emember the exact context of this question, nowhere in my question/comment did I imply using a catch-all net. I could also argue that there's more to life than nitpicking 8yo comments, but that's a different discussion. :) have a great day mate!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore there's also better ways to answer a valid question than implicitly concede... `std::exception` is a meaningless type that you never catch unless you don't care that your program has bugs, that's a definition of catch-all.

Comment: @Sahsahae I don't understand what you mean. I didn't answer the question, I asked the answerer for a clarification, nor did I imply that you should catch a generic `std::exception`. You're assuming I made a statement which I did not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what prompted the question, since you are free to choose the "application" in such cases as you see fit.

The purpose of an exception of object is to indicate the fact that an exception occurred and, usually, to carry some exception-specific information with it from the thrower to the handler. If some type is sufficient for that purpose in your application, then you can use that type as "exception" type. You can throw `int` values, `std::string` values and anything else, if you want. It is entirely up to you.

If all you want to carry from the thrower to the handler is an `int` value, then type `int` will serve that purpose as an "exception" type. That's all there is to it.

C++ does not impose any specific requirements on the types you can throw. For this reason, there is really no such thing as "exception" type or "non-exception" type. What is "exception type" and what is not is determined by you and only by you in your code. You can throw anything, as long as you know how to catch it and how to interpret what you caught.

The first benefit of using class types to represent exceptions is that class types are freely user-definable, i.e. you can easily define as many exception types as you want. Then you can use many independent, non-interfering exception "flows" that throw and catch only exceptions of their respective types.

The second benefit of using class types to represent exceptions is that class types are easily extensible. I.e. at any moment you can add an additional "payload" information to your exception type, and that payload will be carried from the point where the exception was thrown to the point where it is caught and handled.

If you are not interested in any of these benefits, you can simply throw and catch values of type `int` to represent your exceptions. This will work. But I'm almost sure you will quickly run into the limitations of this approach with regard to both maintenance and extensibility.

Comment: The question was not a technical one in the sense that MBZ wasn't asking *if* something other than a `std::exception`-derived object can be thrown, but *when it should be thrown.*  At least that's how I read the question.  Saying, effectively, "you can so long as you know what you're doing," reads a bit vague to me.  If you are asserting that there are legitimate cases where you might throw something not derived from `exception`, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In general, any object which is thrown should derive from
`std::exception`.  There are exceptions, however.  The most
obvious: I've worked on projects which preferred throwing an
`int` to calling `exit()`.  Of course, this only works if 
`main` follows the convention of catching `int` and returning
it.  (The advantage of this is that all local variables will be
destructed, where as they won't if you call `exit()`.)

And in small throw-away test programs, I'll often just throw
a string literal (which can be caught with `char const*`), which
can be immediately output.  (This is *not* a good solution for
any production code, but when you're experimenting in order to
learn something, it seems acceptable.)

Answer (score 0):

As @galop1n answered, you can throw anything you like. But

1. Usually they throw plain data objects rather than pointers to make sure compiler can automatically manage memory so `throw(type())` ---> `catch(type const& e)` as a result
2. Usually they throw something inherited from std::exception to meet expectation of those hoping to be catching everything loggable with `catch(std::exception const& e)`. Though you may contradict that they should not be catching anything that they are not aware of what it is.

Comment: I'm pretty well aware of the word's meaning! I've been asking about [who](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/who?q=who#who), can you elaborate on this? The standard library developers?

Comment: @non-latin-nick - Why don't you post your answer and get a deserved community recognition for both your English and deep subject expertise?

Comment: Side note: _@non-latin-nick_ It's pretty easy to copy /Side note. I'm not going to give an answer for a question I've been close voting for mainly attracting opinion based answers, OK?

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with the general notion that only derivatives of `std::exception` should be thrown. Of course I can agree that throwing objects with complex data or behaviour can be very problematic and should only be done with great care.

However that neither implies any restriction on the inheritance hierarchy of the thrown type, nor on the way (or the reasons why) stack unwinding is employed by your application. And the `throw` operation is just that: a clean and well-defined way of unwinding the stack up to a defined point (the matching `catch`) *without having to involve explicit handlers in the intermediate frames*.

And of course there are legitimate use cases for throwing that do not imply that an error or anything `exception`-al is happening. Think for example of a simple language interpreter, where the host language stack corresponds to the guest language stack. To implement interleaved parallelism in the guest language, stack unwinding is exactly what you need to do when a guest operation blocks (or yields). You want to unwind up to the starting point of the parallelism and try the next of the parallel branches. That situation is neither exceptional nor an error of any kind.

Observe that the keywords are called `throw`/`catch` and that the `exception` concept is not baked into the language in any way. This is (one of) the reason(s) for that.